# Excel: Cannot average blanks determined by formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, average

I have some data in B1:B10 (values) and in C1:C10 (strings) that I want to average.

My values are (from row 1-10):

```
B | C
-----
1 | Approved
1 | Approved
1 | Approved
1 | Approved
  | N/A
  | N/A
  | N/A
1 | Approved
1 | Approved
0 | Disapproved
```

When I enter the following formula in A1 to average the data in column B, I get a result (0.857143), no problem:

```
=AVERAGE(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10)
```

When I instead enter the following formula in D1, I get a #VALUE! error instead, though from what I can tell, the logic is the same (replacing N/A's with blanks):

```
=AVERAGE(
IF(C1="Approved",1,IF(C1="Disapproved",0,IF(C1="N/A","",""))),
IF(C2="Approved",1,IF(C2="Disapproved",0,IF(C2="N/A","",""))),
IF(C3="Approved",1,IF(C3="Disapproved",0,IF(C3="N/A","",""))),
IF(C4="Approved",1,IF(C4="Disapproved",0,IF(C4="N/A","",""))),
IF(C5="Approved",1,IF(C5="Disapproved",0,IF(C5="N/A","",""))),
IF(C6="Approved",1,IF(C6="Disapproved",0,IF(C6="N/A","",""))),
IF(C7="Approved",1,IF(C7="Disapproved",0,IF(C7="N/A","",""))),
IF(C8="Approved",1,IF(C8="Disapproved",0,IF(C8="N/A","",""))),
IF(C9="Approved",1,IF(C9="Disapproved",0,IF(C9="N/A","",""))),
IF(C10="Approved",1,IF(C10="Disapproved",0,IF(C10="N/A","","")))
)
```

What gives, and what do I need to change in order to get 0.857143 as a result in the formula for the strings values in column C?

Also tried changing the "if true" and "if false" parts for N/A with VALUE("") and VALUE(0). With VALUE("") it still results in #VALUE! error, and with VALUE(0) it still counts the blank into the average, which is not desired as I only want an average on the 1's and 0's

**Additional info:** If I split up the formula for the strings to evaluate each one on a separate line, THEN pull an average on THAT range, it works fine.. Though, considering the data set I am working with, I would rather not add them all separately, as it clutters the work space enormously.

Comment: I believe you are trying to get an average out of textual strings. Even `""` is considered a string.

Comment: @JvdV yes, it is what the result is telling me. Though it is not possible to drop the quotes as "blank" (that will give a completely nonsensical result), and when trying to use the VALUE function on the blank result, it still evaluates it the same. When separating the checks in the string checking formula, then after that averaging the range, it works fine. It's amazing if it's not possible to put them all together in one formula..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVERAGE` won't work with text-strings in a given range of numbers. It might skip empty cells (as per your first example), but surely will error out on comparing text in a numeric equation (your second example). So try this instead:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C10,"Approved")/SUM(COUNTIF(C1:C10,{"Approved","Disapproved"}))
```

This will leave `N/A` out of the equation.